# Alt + numeric (ASCII code) input for wpf rich text box with ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, input, keyboard, ribbon

I am currently working on a project that has two components. Ribbon and RichTextBox (System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox).

I am facing a problem where ASCII code (e.g. alt+123 is '{') input does not get reflected because pressing Alt would trigger keytip commands. Especially with Ribbon, there is a quick access toolbar that is triggered by Alt + number.

Is there any suggestion to approach this problem? Or should I give up on ASCII code input for richtextbox?

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit : this is the approach I am taking

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.NumPad0 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad1 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad2 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad3 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad4 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad5 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad6 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad7 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad8 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad9)
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
                return;
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
                return;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```

Ctrl portion would hit on debug but Alt section would not hit.
It worked for several times, got me excited. However, it was only working when I break the code and modify on the fly and ran it. If I recompiled everything and ran the program, it is back to the original state of not hitting the code at all (KeyTip popping up).
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to override the **KeyDown** event. When you evaluate **e.Key**, make sure to additionally evaluate the following in your IF statement:

```
Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt)
```

**Keyboard.IsKeyDown** provides a way to see which modifiers are involved with the current keystroke.

Comment: I thought about overriding OnKeyDown. However, I was not able to come up with the way to successfully cohabit the behavior of KeyTip and input the ASCII input. I just would like to allow alt input if the following inputs are ASCII code Without taking the ability to use shortcut that gets triggered by Alt.

Comment: @publicst119 You could instead check for Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.NumPad0) etc. then the top numbers will still work for ribbon commands.

Comment: Ah that definitely allows me to specifically work with numpads. I started by just returning when Alt is down and numpad is pressed, hopeing this would just take the input after it is done entering. However, the text box still would not allow me to enter a character with ASCII code alt entry. Would there be any suggestions?

Comment: When you are stepping through the overridden KeyDown event, is the NumPad key being passed? If so, how are you implementing e.Handled?

Comment: I have updated original post for the approach I am taking. Ctrl+Numpad would hit the break point no problem, but Alt+Numpad would not. The moment I press Alt the KeyTip pops up on the ribbon. If there were any suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: Suggestion: in traditional hotkey implementations, Alt is only used for menus like (Alt+F) for the file menu. I would suggest using Control instead as this is the more common modifier for Hotkeys.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am not trying to attach any hot keys all the hot keys for shortcuts are in fact using controls.. I am trying to display ASCII code which does not have any other method of displaying other than using alt keys...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on a application I just threw together to try it out:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.NumPad0 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad1 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad2 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad3 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad4 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad5 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad6 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad7 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad8 ||
            e.Key == Key.NumPad9)
            {
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
                }
            }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```

If you're still struggling we might need to see more code - if you can create a simple app using the same principle and give us the XAML code it would help.